# How to run a rake task regularly with using CRON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake, rake-task

I've written a rake task for my Rails application and I'd need to run this tasks regularly with using CRON.

If I have a URL that I need to ping with CRON, I do it like this:

```
0 */6 * * * curl https://www.website.com/something
```

But how to "ping" a rake task?

The application is located in `/home/deployer/apps/myapp-production/current` and is running on DigitalOceal (Ubuntu server - nginx).

Thanks.

**EDIT:** This is my command:

```
0 */6 * * * cd /home/deployer/apps/myapp-production/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:backup
```

But the output is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
```

When I run just `rake db:backup` on my laptop (locally), everything works just well.

Do I have incorrect the path in the CRON task?

**EDIT2:** When I run the command `cd /home/deployer/apps/myapp-production/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:backup` manually from the command line, everything is working, but not from the CRON.

Comment: are you going to be deploying to heroku?

Comment: No, as stated in the OP, it's running on DigitalOcean's servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. It provides nice DSL like:

```
every :day, :at => '12:20am', :roles => [:app] do
  rake "app_server:task"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Alexander, but as I already use CRON for processing some other tasks in the project, I'd welcome to use it also for this one.

Comment: You're welcome. It generates a crontask for you according to dsl. Something like this:
    0 22 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /srv/app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake your_rake'

Comment: I'll mark this answer, because it led me to the successful solution of the problem.

Comment: @user984621 what was your actual solution?